# PHP - convert date from non standard format

Tags: php, date

I am parsing a feed which returns the date in form:

```
20150129180000
```

which should be [yyyy][mm][dd][hours][minutes][seconds]

I tried formatting this with the php date() function:

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $event['start-dt'])
```

and got this:

```
640502-03-05 12:33:20
```

which is obviously not right. Is there a smooth way of converting this, or do I simply need to splice the string manually?

Comment: RTFM: http://php.net/date   date's 2nd arg is a unix timestamp, which is NOT what you're passing in. you've got a numerical string, and should be feeding it to [date_create_from_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-create-from-format.php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Doc](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('YmdHis', '20150129180000');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: Tried to make an edit but stackoverflow wouldn't allow such a small change. Anyway - here's the link to the English docs (original link is to the Russian version of php.net): http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Comment: Thanks! Never knew about this function.

Comment: Fixed the link, from Russion to English version of PHP manual.

Answer (score 3):

You can use preg_replace to format the string

```
$date_str = preg_replace("/^(\d){4}(\d){2}(\d){2}(\d){2}(\d){2}(\d){2}/","$1-$2-$3 $4:$5:$6",$event["start-dt"]);
date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date_str));
```

Or use php's [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object

```
$date = new DateTime($date_str);
```

Or better yet, use the DataTime createFromFormat method

```
$format = "YmdGis";
$dateObj = DateTime::createFromFormat ( $format, $event['start-dt'] );
```

Then you can use [getTimestamp](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimestamp.php) to retrieve the timestamp for calculations, if you need it.

Answer (score 3):

The format is somewhat confusing compared to `date` until you are used to it, but this corresponds to your date string:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('YmdGis', '20150129180000');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```